# Is it possible to ask agents to leave an agentset without relying on their variables in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo, agentset

Although NetLogo has a good set of [primitives allowing for the handy creation of agentsets](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#agentsetgroup), sometimes we might want to ask agents to 'manually' add themselves to an agentset as part of a procedure they're running - for instance, by using `turtle-set`.

Example:

```
globals [
 good-folks
 bad-folks 
]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  set good-folks (turtle-set)
  set bad-folks (turtle-set)
  
  create-turtles 50 [
   ifelse (random 2 < 1)
    [set good-folks (turtle-set good-folks self)]
    [set bad-folks (turtle-set bad-folks self)] 
  ]
end

to go
  ask good-folks [
   do-good-things 
  ]
  
  ask bad-folks [
   do-bad-things 
  ]
end

to do-good-things end
to do-bad-things end
```

The advantage of this approach above is better readability, the possibility to avoid having to create a turtles-own variable and avoid having to resort to `with` or `if` statements - as shown below:

```
turtles-own [
 group 
]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  create-turtles 50 [
   ifelse (random 2 < 1)
    [set group "good folks"]
    [set group "bad folks"]
  ]
end

to go1
  ask turtles with [group = "good folks"] [
   do-good-things 
  ]
  
  ask turtles with [group = "bad folks"] [
   do-bad-things 
  ]
end

; OR

to go2
  ask turtles [
   ifelse (group = "good folks")
    [do-good-things]
    [do-bad-things]
  ]
end

to do-good-things end
to do-bad-things end
```

Especially, it seems to me that the latter approach does not scale up as smoothly as the former, i.e. more groups will require more `with`s or `if`s, instead of just being able to refer to the needed group neatly.

However, I am not aware of a way to do the exact opposite of `set good-folks (turtle-set good-folks self)`, i.e. asking the turtle to 'manually' remove itself from the agentset.

```
; In this case, bad-folks try to recruit some good folks
to do-bad-things
  if (random 3 < 2) [
   ask one-of good-folks [
     set good-folks (turtle-set good-folks - self) ; Leave the good folks <- **How to do this?**
     set bad-folks (turtle-set bad-folks self) ; Join the bad folks
    ] 
  ]
end
```

I know this could be achieved by using a turtles-own variable and then updating agentsets as `set <good/bad>-folks turtles with [...]`, but this is exactly the whole thing that I am trying to avoid in this question: less readable, more variables, more commands etc. And, perhaps equally important, it looks inconsistent with the use that can be done of `turtle-set` to grow the agentset by using it in combination with `self`. It would look easier and more consistent if existed a way to subtract `self` from the agentset - does it exist?

### Update

Jasper's solution (i.e. using breeds instead of agentsets) works as long as the groups that I want to keep track of are mutually exclusive: agents switch from one single breed to another single breed only needing `set breed ...`, which will both make the agent join the new breed **and** leave their previous breed. However, this would not work in case I want to keep track of multiple groups with overlaps: beyond `good-folks` and `bad-folks`, I may have `tall-folks` and `short-folks`. Agents will have to belong to multiple groups simultaneously - something that agentsets can handle while breeds cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, which I realised following some line of thought after Jasper's reply, is actually quite simple and it only requires `other`:

```
to do-bad-things
  if (random 3 < 2) [
   ask one-of good-folks [
     set good-folks (turtle-set other good-folks) ; Leave the good folks
     set bad-folks (turtle-set bad-folks self) ; Join the bad folks
    ] 
  ]
end
```

### Extra cheap thought

This makes me also think that it would be handy if NetLogo had two primitives called `join` and `leave` that worked like:

```
to join [agentset]
  (ifelse
    is-turtle? self [
     set agentset (turtle-set agentset self)
    ]
    is-patch? self [
     set agentset (patch-set agentset self)
    ]
    ; else command:
    [set agentset (link-set agentset self)])
end

to leave [agentset]
  (ifelse
    is-turtle? self [
     set agentset (turtle-set other agentset)
    ]
    is-patch? self [
     set agentset (patch-set other agentset)
    ]
    ; else command:
    [set agentset (link-set other agentset)])
end
```

So that one could do:

```
to do-bad-things
  if (random 3 < 2) [
   ask one-of good-folks [
     leave good-folks
     join bad-folks
    ] 
  ]
end
```

Which feels almost like reading a book rather than reading code; although I recognise the need for it in the end is really minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something with your requirements, but wouldn't breeds let you do this pretty easily?  You can [use `set breed BREED-NAME` to change it](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#breedvar), and it'll auto-remove the turtle from its existing breed, if any.  You even cut a little more code out and I think it looks even clearer, if that is your goal.

```
breed [ good-folks goodie ]
breed [ bad-folks  baddie ]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  create-turtles 50 [
    ifelse (random 2 < 1) [
      set breed good-folks
    ] [
      set breed bad-folks
    ]
  ]
end

to go
  ask good-folks [
   do-good-things 
  ]
  
  ask bad-folks [
   do-bad-things 
  ]
end

to do-good-things end
  
to do-bad-things
  if (random 3 < 2 and any? good-folks) [
    ask one-of good-folks [
      set breed bad-folks  
    ] 
  ]
end
```

Comment: This would work if groups are mutually exclusive, as I admit is the case in my example. However I may want to keep track of some further groups that will have some overlap with `good-folks` and `bad-folks`, such as `tall-folks` and `short-folks` - something that agentsets can handle while breeds cannot. However, following a different line of thought after reading your comment, I found the solution which is actually quite simple.